# Full width background color with centered container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap V4` and I have a `container` class which has 2 columns red and green col-md-6 that sits in the middle of my page.

However I want to add a red background to the left and green to the right of it that fills 100% width.

[image: Bootstrap V4]

**my html**

```
    <section style="background-color:green">
      <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <section>
              <div id="hvc-dyk">
                <header>
                  <h1>Did you know...</h1>
                  <p id="dyk-large">80</p>
                  <p>
                  Lorum ipsum
                  </p>
                </header>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <section>
              This is hre
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Make your background-image a linear-gradient with the 2 colors, each 50% wide...

Comment: Try using a gradient on the `body` element that has a tight transition from red to green in the center.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of creating a Faux background but thought there might be a Bootstrap way of doing it?

Comment: The bootstrap way of doing it would be to use whatever is already available in HTML/CSS, unless that's complicated and bootstrap has an easier solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a linear gradient as the background to simulate this:

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f00 50%, #27a31a 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f00 50%, #27a31a 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f00 50%, #27a31a 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00 50%, #27a31a 50%);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cqq5e8t1/1/